# Why Cant I Log Into the Sims 3?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have recently been having an issue with logging into the Sims 3.  I purchased the game a few weeks ago top find out about this but decided not to worry about it until now.  I am able to log into my account fine but then it takes to me a page about setting up a persona.  Every time I fill out the page and click sign up the page just reloads and I have to enter my information all over again for the same outcome.  I tried logging into the regular site but every time I enter my information there nothing happens.  I am using the in-game browser.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple error that can happen with Orgin's password-recovery function too, the same problem is also known in Ubisoft's UPlay client, it's rather simple to tackle.

The In-Game browser works the same way as any other browser, with Cookies, a **Cache**, history etc.
The solution (technical: Auth Tokens), is that **the Browser Cache needs to be cleared**.

Remove the Cashe Files from your game with the help of this [Page](http://simswiki.info/wiki.php?title=Game_Help:Sims_3_Delete_Cache_Files), where it describes you should delete files for removing the cache, tYOu should delete all the xxxxxCache.package files, don't worry, **They will be regenerated on launch by default!**

If not, Try using a regular browser (FG, GC, IE etc.) to create a Persona, if this don't work either, try cleaning your PC with this funny little program called [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER), it's designed to intelligently clear caches from programs, browsers, system directories etc. and also helps clean temporary data and such, be sure not to install any "extra" things like toolbars on setup ;).